# Is there a way to programmatically create an Azure Active Directory instance?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an application that can synchronize data from Azure Active Directory via the Microsoft Graph API. I'd like to test that functionality in CI. I'd like to be able to check if modifications in the directory are correctly synchronized both with full and incremental synchronization. In order to have the ability to run multiple builds at the same time and have a clean state from the start I would like to have a separate directory per build.

My question is - is there a way to programmatically create an Azure Active Directory and then remove it afterwards, or perhaps a development container feature? I'm not interested in mocking out Azure AD as the aim of these tests would be verifying that the underlying REST API has not changed.

Comment: Are you an MS CSP (Cloud Solution provider)? The APIs for CSPs allow for creation of AAD tenants. If you are not, then AFAIK there is no way.

Comment: Have you considered making a test tenant and then resetting it between tests?

Comment: @juunas I'm afraid I'm not a Cloud Solution Provider. I'll probably go with the test tenant route, however my main gripe is that I have to go for one of the tradeoffs -  I could make the tests not modify the tenant, which would allow me to launch multiple tests at the same time, but I wouldn't be able to test delta sync. Alternatively I could modify and reset the test tenant, but then I'd lose the ability to run multiple builds at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Cloud Solution Providers can create new Azure AD tenants via an API, but for others it is not possible AFAIK.

I suggest making a test tenant and resetting it before/after the tests.
It does mean you can't have multiple test runs in parallel as they would mess with each other.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, for testing incremental synchronization that's probably the only reasonable approach.